# Jquery dialog box issue - replace alert by dialog

Tags: dialog, alert

I try to have a function to display a box with calling dialog('Hello') for example.
I just want to replace the basic function alert by dialog jquery but I don't succeed.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
     **Steps** :
```

> Create a div with id : dialog. Also set it's class
>
> Set the css property of the class **display:none**
>
> Align it in **center** with width and height 25%
>
> Create a function **dialog(str)** that accepts **msg** as a parameter
>
> Use jquery to change the class of div dialog and set the css property **display:block**
>
> In the div that you created place a small ok button and map it's click event to a function that hides the div or set's property : **display:none**

Answer (score 0):

i got this working once i was using it.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#messagebox" ).dialog();
  });
```

And you need some info to go in that box, with this code.

```
  <div id="messagebox" title="some title">
      <p>You type your message here</p>
    </div>
```

you use the id to identify which box, and then the rest gives itself :) good luck.. hope it helps. should be easy.